# trigger help on db2

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

Hi guys I have written a trigger that I hope will generate a message saying

"SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD, PROCEED?"

after a user updates the table `trip`.

In order to qualify as a dead satellite we use a table called `trailer` that shows the last sat date. If the sat hasn't pinged in for over 8 days then it is considered dead.

`active in disp` means the trailer is still a company asset.

Here is where i'm at, can you guys provide me feedback please? and maybe some recommendations? Thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TRIGGER MISSING_TRAILERS
AFTER UPDATE OF TRAILER ON TRIP 
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE DEAD_SAT VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE MSG VARCHAR(70); 

SET DEAD_SAT = COALESCE((SELECT TRAILER_ID FROM TRAILER WHERE LAST_SAT_DATE < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 8 DAYS AND ACTIVE_IN_DISP = 'True'),'OK')

IF DEAD_SAT <> 'OK' THEN
SET MSG = 'SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD, PROCEED?'  
END IF;
END
```

Comment: This sounds like application logic rather than something that belongs in a trigger.  Triggers are typically used to maintain data integrity, and maintain summary tables.  They are not typically used to send messages back to a user.

Comment: i know but we have triggers that send messages back to a user as well

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER BT_CU_BEFORE_UPDATE_BROKER_RATE
NO CASCADE BEFORE UPDATE OF DECLARED_VALUE ON TLORDER
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O
FOR EACH ROW
MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE CUST_GROUP VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE FSC VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE DETAIL_LINE VARCHAR(3);
DECLARE MSG VARCHAR(70);

Comment: SET CUST_GROUP = COALESCE((SELECT CUSTOMER_GROUP FROM CLIENT WHERE CLIENT_ID = N.BILL_TO_CODE),'NONE');
SET FSC = COALESCE((SELECT 'YES' FROM ACHARGE_TLORDER A WHERE A.DETAIL_LINE_ID = N.DETAIL_LINE_ID AND CHARGE_AMOUNT <> 0 AND ACODE_ID LIKE 'FS_%' AND MANUAL_AMT = 'False' FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY),'NO');
SET DETAIL_LINE = COALESCE((SELECT 'YES' FROM TLDTL WHERE ORDER_ID = N.DETAIL_LINE_ID AND PICK_ID = 0 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY),'NO');

Comment: IF CUST_GROUP = 'BROKER' AND (O.DECLARED_VALUE <> N.DECLARED_VALUE OR O.DECLARED_VALUE <> 0) THEN
  IF FSC = 'NO' THEN 
  SET MSG = 'NEED NON MANUAL FUEL APPLIED FIRST';
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75010' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = MSG;
  SET N.DECLARED_VALUE = O.DECLARED_VALUE;
  END IF;
    IF DETAIL_LINE = 'NO' THEN
    SET MSG = 'MUST ADD DETAIL LINE FIRST';
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75010' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = MSG;
    SET N.DECLARED_VALUE = O.DECLARED_VALUE;
    END IF; 
END IF;
END

Comment: @GordonLinoff is right. Even if the trigger raises an error message, your application will still need to know how to handle the error and turn that into a prompt that asks the user to proceed or not, and decide what to do with the user's response.

Comment: You are right, I am currently trying to figure that out ! I am under the impression that all sqlstates will cause a roll back

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEAD_TRAILERS_NOTIFY
AFTER UPDATE OF TRAILER ON TRIP 
REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC

DECLARE DEAD_SAT VARCHAR(10); 
DECLARE MSG VARCHAR(70); 

SET DEAD_SAT = COALESCE((SELECT TRAILER_ID FROM TRAILER WHERE LAST_SAT_DATE < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 8 DAYS AND N.TRAILER = TRAILER_ID),'OK');



    IF DEAD_SAT <> 'OK' AND USER NOT IN ('VISTAR','TM4WIN') THEN
    SET MSG = 'SAT ON TRAILER IS DEAD. PLEASE GET IT REPLACED'; 
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '75010' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = MSG;
    END IF;
END
```